# How to Add Parent node using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm new to XSLT. I would like to add parent node for existing child nodes using XSLT. My XML file looks like below

Before Conversion

```
  <Library>
        .
        .//There is more nodes here
        .
        <CD>
            <Title> adgasdg ag</Title>
            .
            .//There is more nodes here
            .
        </CD>
         .
        .//There is more nodes here
        .
        <CLASS1>
         <CD>
            <Title> adgasdg ag</Title>
            .
            .//There is more nodes here
            .
        </CD>
        </CLASS1>
        </Library>
```

After Conversion

```
  <Library>
  <Catalog>
    <CD>
      <Title> adgasdg ag</Title>
    </CD>
  </Catalog>
  <Class1>
    <Catalog>
      <CD>
        <Title> adgasdg ag</Title>
      </CD>
    </Catalog>
  </Class1>
</Library>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the element `Catalog` you can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CD">
        <Catalog>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </Catalog>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would normally do exactly what @markdark suggests (override the identity transform), but if you don't need to modify anything other than adding `Catalog`, you could also do this...

**XSLT 2.0** (also works as 1.0)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <Catalog>
                <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
            </Catalog>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```